# Mapping traveller routes using Carto?

Tags: carto, routing

Hi have a database from one app that was used to register travels made by the staff. The recorded rows looks like:

- travel id (#)
- leg id (#)
- leg departure (date time and city)
- leg arrival (date time and city)
- staff member info
- other aggregable fields like the method of transportation, flight no, etc.

What is the data modeling standards used to connect the dots correctly so trips could be grouped by members, from-to (bearing in mind that one trip could have connexions) and preserve an order so I can query the last trip (on the time-series bars) and determine that the member is currently on that city.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a route between two points in CARTO, you would need to use [CARTO routing functions](https://carto.com/location-data-services/routing/), [`cdb_route_point_to_point()`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/dataservices-api/routing-functions/#cdbroutepointtopointorigin-geometrypoint-destination-geometrypoint-mode-text-options-text-units-text) when you have just origin and destination, and [`cdb_route_with_waypoints()`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/dataservices-api/routing-functions/#cdbroutewithwaypointswaypoints-geometrypoint-mode-text-options-text-units-text) when you have more than two locations.